# Use variables to the class of an element

Tags: node.js, node-blade

I use the blade template engine in node. I want to use variables to the class of an element.

Is this possible?

Update:

i found. just like attributes

`li(class="#{friend.status}",userId="#{friend.userId}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the `class` attribute:

```
- var classNames = ["bar", "hello", "world"]
li.foo(class=classNames)
```

would render as:

```
<li class="bar hello world foo"></li>
```